# external library (pod) showing errors after updating Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

[image]

I've updated Xcode to the latest and all these errors came. Then I downgraded my Xcode, but the errors still there.

Comment: I guess that's an issue with Xcode4.2? Is the pod isn't compatible to Swift 4.2?

Comment: It seems like that library wasn't updated to the latest Swift version and your project's Swift compiler version setting was most probably changed to 4.2, you can re-upgrade Xcode, just make sure you keep the Swift version of your pod's project at 4.1 (or whatever it was previously).

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `Pods` project
2. Select `Target` of the pod with errors
3. Open `Build Settings` tab
4. Search for `Swift Language Version`(`SWIFT_VERSION`)
5. Set proper Swift version for the pod
6. Build your project again
7. If build fails you set wrong Swift version, so repeat from 5
8. If some other pod will generate errors of this kind repeat from 2

Also, you may set some Swift version for `Pods` project itself, to set some default version.